# how to have one field of one document in stream builder?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have a collection called 'Chapters' and a document in that collection called '0'. I have a field called url in that document. url contains a url that is to be used in a network image widget. I want this to show realtime data so it should change based on the value of url.

How do I show this in a stream builder?

Before, I would do something like this:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('comments').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Connecting...');
          final int cardLength = snapshot.data.documents.length;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: cardLength,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final DocumentSnapshot _card = snapshot.data.documents[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(_card['name']),
                subtitle: Text(_card['feedback']),
              );
            },
          );
```

But, this was to display 'name' and 'feedback' of every document present in the collection. How would I do it if I wanted to show one field of just one document?

Comment: in snapshot it has url ? i mean if you use _card['url'] then it prints url or not ?